# How to write style for hover on button in C# (in ASP.NET)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, styles

how can i write a style for hover for a button in c# in asp.net?
i wrote this codes, but i don't know how to write for hover for it?

```
button1.Style[" border-style"] = "solid";
                button1.Style["background-color"] = "#063a83";
                button1.Style[" border-width"] = "3px";
                button1.Style[" color"] = "White";
                button1.Style[" font-family"] = "Tahoma";
                button1.Style[" border-color"] = "Gray";
                button1.Style[" border-radius"] = "10px";
                button1.Style[" background-image"] = "url(../images/products/zoom2.png)";
                button1.Style[" background-repeat"] = "no-repeat";
                button1.Style[" padding"] = "10px";
                button1.Style["Cursor"] = "pointer";
```

i want to write this for hover:

```
 .btn:hover
    {
       background-color :#202020 ; 
       cursor:pointer;
    }
```

Comment: Styles should only be written in CSS stylesheets, not in C# code (separation of concerns). You just need to give your button a class (like `.btn`) and write styles for that

Comment: but the button create when reading data from database and I cant write: string s= "<asp:button ...... cssclass=btn" ></asp:button>"  Panel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(s)); i should to create button with button class.

Comment: You are creating the button dynamically? If so can you please show that code?

Comment: You can meet your requirements and separation of concerns by adding a Jquery call at the end of your aspx makeup which apply your onhover style to all button/input elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `CssClass` to you button like this:

```
Button button2 = new Button();

button2.Text = "buy";
button2.ID = ddr[2].ToString();
button2.CssClass = "btn"; //add a css class

button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(detail_Click);
Panelproduct.Controls.Add(button2);
```

Then in your css stylesheet add styles for that class, like so:

```
.btn{
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: #063a83;
    /*more styles*/
}

.btn:hover{
       background-color :#202020 ; 
       cursor:pointer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my code:

```
Button button2 = new Button();

                button2.Text = "buy";
                  button2.ID = ddr[2].ToString();
                button2.Style[" border-style"] = "solid";
                button2.Style["background-color"] = "#063a83";
                button2.Style[" border-width"] = "3px";
                button2.Style[" color"] = "White";
                button2.Style[" font-family"] = "Tahoma";
                button2.Style[" border-color"] = "Gray";
                button2.Style[" border-radius"] = "10px";
                button2.Style[" background-image"] = "url(../images/products/zoom2.png)";
                button2.Style[" background-repeat"] = "no-repeat";
                button2.Style[" padding"] = "10px";
                button2.Style["Cursor"] = "pointer";


               button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(detail_Click);

                Panelproduct.Controls.Add(button2);
```